# Mongodb add an element to an array in specific order

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I would like to push a new value to an array in a specific position but although I tried differents things I can do it. Can someone help me?

My document is:

```
    {

  "_id" : ObjectId("55528f000000000000000000"),
  "contractId" : "55528f000000000000000000",
  "field1": [
    {
      "name":"example",
      "backendData": {
        "map": {
          "7552" : "RTEST",
          "3511" : "TESTR",
          "5312" : "JKTLE",
          "5310" : "INVTS"
        }
      },
      "data": {
        "defaultOrder": [
          "7552",
          "3511",
          "5312",
          "5310"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried with set, but I didn't find a way to add the element in the position I want, then I tried with push but it's not working. I did something like that:

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": ObjectId("55528f000000000000000000"),
  
},
{
  "$push": {
    "field1.$[i].data.$.defaultOrder": {
      "$each": [
        "9999"
      ],
      "$position": 2
    }
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "i.entities": {
        $elemMatch: {
          "name": "example"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

And although it gives me a match it doesn't make any change

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

Expected outcome:

```
{

  "_id" : ObjectId("55528f000000000000000000"),
  "contractId" : "55528f000000000000000000",
  "field1": [
    {
      "name":"example",
      "backendData": {
        "map": {
          "7552" : "RTEST",
          "3511" : "TESTR",
          "5312" : "JKTLE",
          "5310" : "INVTS"
        }
      },
      "data": {
        "defaultOrder": [
          "7552",
          "3511",
          "9999",
          "5312",
          "5310"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please try this (edited both 2nd and 3rd parts):

```
db.collection.update({"_id": ObjectId("55528f000000000000000000")},
{"$push": {"field1.$[i].data.defaultOrder":
    {"$each": ["9999"], "$position": 2}}},
{arrayFilters: [ { "i.name": "example" } ]})
```

See:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/8o57t4tlnm6

Comment: Works perfectly. I see what was my mistake. Thank you so much.